# Creating new active directory account from an asp.net webpage

Tags: asp.net, active-directory

I'm 14 and I am really stuck. I wish to have an ASP.NET webpage that will enable users to create a new account in an organizational container. I have seen many pages on this but I just keep getting stuck.

Also, if this is possible, once the user has signed up would it be possible to run a script to enable the user for Office Communications Server 2007, or will I have to set the script as a cron job every 2 minutes?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Yes, but I just get stuck with everything. Sorry its a bit vauge

Comment: I'd be tempted to suggest sharing some code as otherwise this will stay vague which may not help you as it could well be similar to those pages you've seen.

Comment: I don't have the code anymore but it was just a load of connection strings and I kept getting a parser error saying that it could not connect securely to my server?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do it in a classic asp page:

```
Set objContainer = GetObject("LDAP://OU=OUtoPut,DC=YOUR,DC=ORG")
Set objUser = objContainer.Create("User", "CN=" & strCN)

objUser.sAMAccountName = strCN
objUser.givenName = strFName
objUser.sn = strLName
objUser.FullName = strCN
objUser.displayName = strCN
objUser.UserPrincipalName = strCN & "@your.org"
objUser.SetInfo
objUser.SetPassword strPass
objUser.pwdLastSet = 0
objUser.SetInfo
objUser.AccountDisabled = False
objUser.SetInfo
```

probably a little overdone toward the end with the setinfos, but it works.